# Kernel compilation of version 2.4 on a system running 3.2.0

Tags: 12.04, kernel

My current kernel version on with my OS running on is 3.2.0.

Can I compile a kernel of version 2.4.0 on it?

Is there any perfect kernel documentation available? (As I see different ways of compiling kernel, expecting a unified documentation which lists all possible ways)

Comment: Please do not cross-post to mutiple SE sites: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68034/relation-between-the-kernel-version-and-os-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest Kernel version available for Ubuntu 12.04 is `3.2.0-23` as you can see at the Ubuntu Package webpage: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel/.

So you can't install it in the 12.04 as it's not supported.